# Can Geometry Node Point Instances be exported as animation in FBX?

Tags: instances

Just wondering how to export Geometry node Point Instances that are animated.I have tried exporting as FBX and the instances don't show up.Can anybody please help me on this one?

Comment: Alembic works for that animation

Comment: Thank you I will try that!

Comment: It works Thank You, but do textures and materials need to be baked as they did not show up?

Comment: Yes, you have to either bake before and use the textures or make your material nodes after that

Comment: Hey Emir, thanks again, I am new to Blender after 12 years Maya!